# "Valid identity signing not found" - (Xcode 4.5.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, distribution, provisioning

I created my Distribution profile, downloaded it and then when I added it to my Xcode organiser the profile is yellow saying: "Valid identity signing not found".

I've looked all over the internet for a solution but I have had no luck. Please can you help me.

Comment: Do you have the Developer Certificate downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

Import the distribution certificate with valid privatekey